# Modifying header.php for Avada Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Test Site Example: http://cincinnati-website-design.net/sandbox/

I am using the Avada Theme and can't seem to get help through support. They just tell me to go find a developer.

I am trying to get the "page-title-container" to appear on the main index/HOME page. It appears correctly on every other page, but apparently it is designed to NOT show on the main index or HOME.

header.php snippet:

```
<?php if(of_get_option('page_title_bar', 'yes') == 'yes'): ?>
<?php if(((is_page() || is_single() || is_singular('avada_portfolio')) && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pyre_page_title', true) == 'yes') && !is_front_page()): ?>
<div class="page-title-container">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php kriesi_breadcrumb(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(is_home() && !is_front_page() && get_post_meta($slider_page_id, 'pyre_page_title', true) == 'yes'): ?>
<div class="page-title-container">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo of_get_option('blog_title', 'Blog'); ?></h1>
        <?php kriesi_breadcrumb(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(is_search()): ?>
<div class="page-title-container">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php _e('Search results for:', 'Avada'); ?> <?php echo get_search_query(); ?></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(is_archive()): ?>
<div class="page-title-container">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php kriesi_breadcrumb(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="main" style="overflow:hidden !important;">
    <div class="row">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code:

```
is_front_page()
```

is what checks for the front page.

try removing the following from your above code:

```
&& !is_front_page()
```

it appears twice and is telling the script to not do what follows it, when on the front page.

Comment: I must have borked a parenthesis or something. Tried that, but failed. Thanks so much for straightening me out!